# How to get user model in components template? OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I tried print user name and email in component template:

```
<td>{{ Partners.getUser(partner.partner_id).name }}</td>
<td>{{ Partners.getUser(partner.partner_id).email }}</td>
```

Page code:

```
use RainLab\User\Models\User;

//Get one user
function onStart()
{
    $this['partners'] = new class {
        public function getUser($id) {

        $user = User::all()->where('id', $id)->first();

        return $user;
    }
};
}
```

but the function does not print anything. can there be other ways to do this?

Comment: what does `var_dump($user)` prints?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz , nothing.. var_dump does not work

Comment: Its likely that your function isn't actually getting called, as var_dump probably 'works'  also.... $user = User::find($id);

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky to call that function :)

```
use RainLab\User\Models\User;

function onStart() {

    $this['getUser'] = function($id) {
        $user = \Auth::findUserById($id);
        // OR $user = User::all()->where('id', $id)->first();
        return $user;
    };

}
```

> Now its time to call it ;)

```
{{ getUser.call(this['page'], 1).id }}
```

so here `1` <- is user id

for you

```
{{ getUser.call(this['page'], partner.partner_id).name }}
```

> **partner.partner_id** is your `user id`

Answer (score 0):

To return the user model that is signed in, use Auth::getUser instead.

```
function onStart(){
    $user = Auth::getUser();
    dd($user); 
}
```

[You can see the documentation for more information](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user)